# Execute update clause even with errors

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm doing some script testing and I want to make sure that if the Update Clause I'm testing in this Try Catch :

```
BEGIN TRY
   BEGIN TRAN
   UPDATE NAME
    SET NAME.ADDBY = 
    (CASE WHEN NAME.ADDBY = 'CONVERSION' THEN 'CONVERTED'  
    WHEN NAME.ADDBY = 'CJDOG'THEN 'CJDAREME' 
    WHEN NAME.ADDBY = 'npalerm' THEN 'REALLYLONGDETAILEDTEXT'
  ELSE NAME
   END)
   COMMIT TRAN 
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   IF @@TRANCOUNT >0
   PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
        ROLLBACK TRAN 

END CATCH
PRINT @@TRANCOUNT
```

fails, that other rows are updated and only the ones that didn't error go through.
**Currenty** because it is in the TRY CATCH there is a ROLLBACK that makes sure nothing goes through.

But when I try to run just the UPDATE part the errors terminates the whole script, instead of updating those that do not cause an error, in this case npalerm is too long in the case.

Any Ideas?

I know its a long desc I could've just included the Update but for detailed purpose I included it in the Catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to update the rows individually and catch the errors on each row rather than catching errors on the entire table/view update, you would need to wrap the whole thing in a [cursor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx).

Be aware that cursors are more resource intensive and slower than set-based commands.